# Why is my server showing error on the browser "This site can't be reached ERR_UNSAFE_PORT" even when it is running perfectly on the terminal?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I made a index.html file and index.js and server.js.
Inside server.js I have written the following code:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path" );

const app = express();


app.use("/static",express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "frontend", "static")));


app.get("/*", (req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,"frontend","index.html"));

});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5060, ()=> console.log("Server Running..."));
```

No error is shown by the vs code and it is working fine in terminal but giving error msg when I am trying to load the application on chrome browser with localhost:5060 url with ERR_UNSAFE_PORT error. Please suggest some way to resolve this.

Comment: just give this app.listen(5060, ()=> console.log("Server Running...")); and then try to load localhost:5060

Comment: or print the port which is coming from process.env.PORT and load the URL accordingly.

Comment: @Manit I have tried using this too it is still showing the same error.

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error in the terminal of VScode but when I am running the server on localhost:5060 in my browser then it is showing error like " This site can't be reached".

Comment: can you try running it on port 3001? I was able to reproduce your issue but when I switched to another port, it worked.

Comment: @Manit Thankyou so much now that I have changed it to 3001 it is working.

Comment: Check environment variable for PORT. Looks like you are not using 5060. If PORT is not defined then only, 5060 will be used.

Comment: yeah, so basically 5060 is considered to be an unsafe port. This contains a list of unsafe ports - https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/refs/heads/main/net/base/port_util.cc and are not recommended to be used. Will you be okay in upvoting my answer, once I post it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, there are a bunch of ports which are considered unsafe by chrome browser which includes 5060 which you were specifying earlier. That's why earlier you were getting "ERR_UNSAFE_PORT" error when you were trying to load localhost:5060.

From the program perspective, there isn't anything wrong. And at first glance everything will look okay. The problem starts when chrome identifies the port and declares it unsafe. This is done by the browser to prevent XSRF so, that someone doesn't use chrome as a proxy to attack your services.

How do you know which are the ports we are not supposed to use? Refer at this link which provides a list of blocked ports on chrome browser - https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/refs/heads/main/net/base/port_util.cc

Final program would look like:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path" );

const app = express();


app.use("/static",express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "frontend", "static")));


app.get("/*", (req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,"frontend","index.html"));

});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3001, ()=> console.log("Server Running..."));
```