# trying to connect backend to frontend using axios but unsure why the data is not rendering

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

First, I'll show my backend code to see how I'm pulling the information, then ill show the data, and the model of what I'm precisely pulling

```
export const getPosts = async (req, res, next) => {
    
    try {
        const post = await Post.find()
        if(!post) return next(createError('No Posts Found'))
        res.status(200).json(post)  
    } catch (error) {
        next(error)
    }
}

export const createPost = async (req, res, next) => {
    const body = req.body
    try {
        const post = new Post({ ...body })
        if(!post) return next(createError('Cannot create Post'))
        await post.save()
        return res.status(200).json(post) 
    } catch (error) {
        next(error)
    }
}
```

I'm not using the createPost function in the frontend of my code; I'm strictly keeping it in the backend. Now, here's my model schema of how the data is shaped.

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    img: {type: String, required: true},
    title: {type: String, required: true},
    desc: {type: String, required: true},
    date: {type: String, default: Date},
}, {
    timestamps: true
})

export default mongoose.model("Post", PostSchema);
```

Now, onto the frontend. Im using axios to pull the information

```
 const [events, setEvents] = useState([])
      const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  
      const url = 'http://localhost:6000/api/events'
      
      useEffect(() => {
         const getEvents = async () => {
             const { data: res } = await axios.get(url)
             setEvents(res)
         };
         getEvents()
      }, [])
```

Here's where I'm mapping and attempting to load the data on the screen.

```
{loading ? <h1>Loading Events...</h1> : 
        <div> 
            {events.map(event => (
            <div>
            <div>
            <div key={event._id}>
                <img src={event.img} alt="Jamil the founder" />
                <div>
                <p>{event.title}</p>
                <p>{event.desc}</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            </div>
            </div>
            ))}               
        </div>}
```

[image: Here's a photo of how the data is being pulled]

When I console.log it here's what appears
[image]

Heres how I'm setting up my connection in the backend

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import postRoutes from './Routes/post.js'
import cors from 'cors'

const app = express();
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

dotenv.config()

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;

mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_ACCESS,  {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  }, () => console.log('Database Connected'))

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    const status = err.status || 500
    const message = err.message || "something went wrong"
    return res.status(status).json({
        success: false,
        status,
        message
    })
})

app.use(
    cors({
      methods: ["GET", "POST"],
      credentials: true,
    })
  );

app.use('/api', postRoutes)

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`))
```

Comment: Use console logs after each line and see where the output is not as expected.

Comment: I updated the question, you can now see what happens when I console log

Comment: Clearly, the API request has failed. Now try googling for that error message. `javascript ERR_UNSAFE_PORT`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my server showing error on the browser "This site can't be reached ERR\_UNSAFE\_PORT" even when it is running perfectly on the terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67951034/why-is-my-server-showing-error-on-the-browser-this-site-cant-be-reached-err-un)

Comment: So i implemented cors in the backend and it removed all the errors in the frontend but it still never solved my issue of displaying the information, which is weird. I also changed the port to 4000

Comment: CORs is not the issue here. `ERR_UNSAFE_PORT` is caused because of some security measures by your browser. Changing the port to something else (like 3000, 3001, etc) should solve the issue. Can you paste the error you get after changing the port?

Comment: I changed the port to 3001, 3002 and 3000. The only time I get an error is when the port is set to 3000 and it reads "GET http://localhost:3000/ 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: The backend server, then, might be hosted on some other port. Did you change the PORT in backend as well?

Comment: In your server, change `const PORT = 3011;` and in your frontend, change `http://localhost:6000/api/events` to `http://localhost:3011/api/events`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set an object as response to the data you get from axios, i think you just do a typo since data is one of the property from the response, how about trying like this :

```
 const [events, setEvents] = useState([])
      const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  
      const url = 'http://localhost:6000/api/events'
      
      useEffect(() => {
         const getEvents = async () => {
             const res = await axios.get(url)
             setEvents(res.data)
         };
         getEvents()
      }, [])
```

update2:  this will work since you re using ES6 so you can use top lvl await :

```
 import "dotenv/config"; //do it like this and remove the extra line "dotenv.config()"
   
    //......

    // optional to listnening if you re connected
    mongoose.connection.once("open", () => {
        console.log("connection ready!");
    })
   
 try {
      await mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_ACCESS);
     } catch (err) {
       console.log(`Process failed... ${err}`);
     }
    
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000; //or the port of your choice
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
            console.log(`app is running on port ${PORT}...`)
     });
```

than change your URL on the frontend to match the port.

Comment: I tried that, and it does not work.

Comment: @Kobe Sutton did you get the data if you console.log(events) just before your attempt to load the data  with map  ?

Comment: No, im not recieving any data

Comment: @Kobe Sutton  I just saw your error I updated the answer for you to check, otherwise show how you set out your connection

Comment: I edited the post so now you can see how my connection is set up

Comment: @Kobe Sutton are you sure you update the URL on your frontend ? I update again the connection just in case

Answer (score 0):

**6000** port already reserved port change to 3000 and then try again.

Comment: when it do that it says "cannot GET /"

Comment: make sure you change the port on front end also to **const url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/events'**

Comment: also restart server too.